# MVC4 + OAuth , what provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

Ok, I'm close to a meltdown here.
I just want to play around a bit with OAuth and test some integration with different providers.

So I read this article http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

It turns out that I have version 2 of microsoft.web.webpages.oauth and I'm supposed to have version 4 (?) 
Atleast I get a runtime error saying that I need v4.

Where what and when do I get that and why does the error appear? is that MVC 4 that somehow requests it?

I have tried to install countless of nuget packages for oauth, and I seem to be out of luck.
Anyone who can point me in the right direction here?